# How can I implement a viewed system for my website's posts?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

Here is my current structure:

```
// posts
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id | title  | content  | author_id | date_time  |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1 | 435       | 1468111492 |
| 2  | title2 | content2 | 657       | 1468113910 |
| 3  | title3 | content3 | 712       | 1468113791 |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+

// viewed
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
| id | user_id_or_ip | post_id | date_tiem  |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
| 1  | 324           | 1       | 1468111493 |
| 2  | 546           | 3       | 1468111661 |
| 3  | 135.54.12.1   | 1       | 1468111691 |
| 5  | 75            | 1       | 1468112342 |
| 6  | 56.26.32.1    | 2       | 1468113190 |
| 7  | 56.26.32.1    | 3       | 1468113194 |
| 5  | 75            | 2       | 1468112612 |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM viewed WHERE post_id = :id) AS total_viewed
 FROM posts p
WHERE id = :id
```

Currently I've faced with a huge date for `viewed` table. Well what's wrong with my table structure *(or database design)*? In other word how can I improve it?

A website like stackoverflow has almost 12 million posts. Each post has *(on average)* 500 viewed. So the number of `viewed`'s rows should be:

```
12000000 * 500 = 6,000,000,000 rows
```

Hah `:-)` .. Honestly I cannot even read that number *(btw that number will grow up per sec)*. Well how stackoverflow handles the number of viewed for each post? Will it always calculate `count(*)` from `viewed` per post showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think that there is a `viewed` table like yours on stackoverflow's database? Raw logs are very costly to maintain on a relational database, and on high-traffic websites, caching has a very important role, and it is almost impossible to conserve full logs of everything (they are summarized). For Wikipedia, for example, we maintain a complete different infrastructure for analytics (fed with Apache Kafka from Varnish and Mediawiki), and then an API is offered that can be called from Mediawiki itself: https://tools.wmflabs.org/pageviews/?project=en.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=user&range=latest-20&pages=Main_Page

If you had to implement `viewed X times` functionality within the datbase, you could denormalize the tables by maintaining an extra column as part of the main posts table:

```
// posts
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | title  | content  | author_id | date_time  | view_count |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1 | 435       | 1468111492 | 3          |
| 2  | title2 | content2 | 657       | 1468113910 | 2          |
| 3  | title3 | content3 | 712       | 1468113791 | 2          |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

For several reasons, in some cases a separate table may be preferred (e.g. to avoid making the main table hot; if there is a very normalized table such as post_properties; to save space if most posts have 0 views)- it all depends on external factors. In that case, you would have:

```
// posts_views
+---------+------------+
| post_id | view_count |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 3          |
| 2       | 2          |
| 3       | 2          |
+---------+------------+
```

And then:

```
SELECT posts.*, post_views.view_count
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_views
ON posts.id = post_views.post_id
WHERE id = :id
```

(The `LEFT JOIN` is in case you have posts without view counts, if not, just use a regular `JOIN`)

In both cases, after a "view" is added, additionally (or alternatively) add 1 to the number of views in a SERIALIZED way.

Try to avoid logs on relational databases (specially MySQL). You can bring the summaries back after being analysed.

Comment: Ah I see. thank you, upvote .. Also based on some article that I've read recently, I can use a `TRIGGER` plus your table suggestion. Like this `INSERT INTO posts_views ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ++` .. *(noted that `post_id` column is unique)*

Comment: @Stack in case you need some history, add a date to the `posts_views` table and make the `(post_id, date)` the PK, that way you have more rows per post to work with (if you need to show some graphs for example) but still the granularity good. One post can gather thousand views a day and you only have one row, then when the post is "forgotten", no rows are added until someone finds it and "ressurects" it again, bringing more viewers (again only for one or few days).